# How can I transform the following equation into matrix form and differenciate?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, optimization, self-learning, gradient-descent

How can I put the follwing equation into matrix form and differenciate with reapect to a and b?

$f(a,b) = \sum_{i=1}^4\{(a+bx_i) -y_i\}^2$

Answer (score 0):

Let vector $v$ be
$$v=\begin{pmatrix} a+bx_1-y_1, & a+bx_2-y_2, & a+bx_3-y_3, &a+bx_4-y_4,\end{pmatrix}$$
Now, doing matrix multiplication, your equation can be written as
$$f(a,b)=vv'$$
where $v'$ is the transpose of vector $v$. Basically, if you have sums of products like in this case, you can write it with matrix multiplication.

I will leave the differentiation to you.